# PyroCMS outputting profile custom fields

Tags: pyrocms

I have the following custom fields in my users profile. Something I've noticed is that these will output the currently logged in users fields. How do I get these fields to appear for the currently viewing user profile? I need to be able to see the selected user profiles data and not the logged in users data.

```
{{ user:your_address }}, {{ user:address_line3 }}, {{ user:state }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a user id to the user plugin tags.

```
{{ user:your_address user_id="4" }}
```

Or us the profile tag if you have more than one tag.

```
{{ user:profile user_id="4" }}

{{ your_address }}
{{ address_line3 }}

{{ /user:profile }}
```

This is for PyroCMS version 2.1. If you have an older version you may need to update the user plugin.

From here: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/plugins/user

**Edit**

You can pass a variable to the user tags like so.

```
{{ user:your_address user_id="{{ user_id_var }}" }}
```

But you will need to set the id when you build your template in the controller, and pass the variable to the page somehow (via a URI segment?).

```
$this->template->user_id_var = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Comment: I am integrating Google Maps in with user profiles. On every profile, the users address will be taken from the field and placed into Google Maps. So I need the id to be unique to the person's profile. Is this possible with your method?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Every user has a unique id - it's assigned in the database. How are you passing the address to Google maps?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WWK0Aj8B - I am passing it by using something called gmap3. and what i mean is how do i get the id of the user profile to show in the user_id="" field? Since that number is static and not dynamic, it'll only show the address of one user across all profiles.

Comment: Thanks man, this has been a big help so far. That's pretty smart programming the way you utilized the uri segment. I never would have thought about that. But I have one more question. As I'm new to PyroCMS I don't know how to pass the controller var to the view and I cannot seem to find documentation on it. Can you please explain that to me? :)

Comment: The last line of my answer is how you pass a variable to the template. Did you make your own module or are you using a normal page?